# Python (pandas): store a data frame in hdf5 with a multi index

Tags: python, sql, pandas, hdf5, multi-index

I need to work with large dimension data frame with multi index, so i tried to create a data frame to learn how to store it in an hdf5 file.
The data frame is like this: (with the multi index in the first 2 columns)

```
Symbol    Date          0

C         2014-07-21    4792
B         2014-07-21    4492
A         2014-07-21    5681
B         2014-07-21    8310
A         2014-07-21    1197
C         2014-07-21    4722
          2014-07-21    7695
          2014-07-21    1774
```

I'm using the pandas.to_hdf but it creates a "Fixed format store", when I try to select the datas in a group:

```
store.select('table','Symbol == "A"')
```

it returns some errors and the main problem is this

```
TypeError: cannot pass a where specification when reading from a Fixed format store. this store must be selected in its entirety
```

Then i tried to append the DataFrame like this:

```
store.append('ts1',timedata)
```

and that should create a table, but that gives me another error:

```
TypeError: [unicode] is not implemented as a table column
```

So i need the code to store the data frame in a table in hdf5 format and to select the datas from a single index (for that purpose i found this code: `store.select('timedata','Symbol == "A"')` )

Comment: pls report your pandas version, numpy version, python version, os, and show how you created that frame.

Comment: pandas 0.14.1,
numpy 1.8.1
system version 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jun  2 2014, 12:48:16) \n[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)]

Comment: I created the data frame extracting datas from a sqlite3 data frame I created with random datas, random random symbols and random quantity: <br/> 

`doubleIndex = c.execute("SELECT date, symbol, qty FROM stocks")  
double = c.fetchall()  
serie = pandas.DataFrame(double,columns=['Date','Symbol', 'DateValue'])
serie['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(serie['Date'])
serie = serie.sort('Date',ascending=True)`

Comment: And that's how I created the MultiIndex:

`index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays([serie['Symbol'],serie['Date']], names=['Symbol','Date'])`

Comment: you probably have unicode, try ``df[column] = df[column].astype(str)`` to change the unicode to string. cannot store unicode in py2.7. you should use ``read_sql`` as well (and possibly turn off the unicode options in sqlite3)

Comment: I tried to convert the column of the data frame to str, but it didn't worked: when I tried to `df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',format='table')`
It gave me the same error:
`TypeError: [unicode] is not implemented as a table column`

Comment: How can I turn off the unicode option in sqlite3?

Comment: no idea. you need to fix that before moving forward.

Comment: I solved the problem changing the unicode to string also in the index:
`index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays([serie['Symbol'].astype(str),serie['Date']], names=['Symbol','Date'])
`

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example

```
In [8]: pd.__version__
Out[8]: '0.14.1'

In [9]: np.__version__
Out[9]: '1.8.1'

In [10]: import sys

In [11]: sys.version
Out[11]: '2.7.3 (default, Jan  7 2013, 09:17:50) \n[GCC 4.4.5]'

In [4]: df = DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(9,-1),index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('abc'),date_range('20140721',periods=3)],names=['symbol','date']),columns=['value'])

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
                   value
symbol date             
a      2014-07-21      0
       2014-07-22      1
       2014-07-23      2
b      2014-07-21      3
       2014-07-22      4
       2014-07-23      5
c      2014-07-21      6
       2014-07-22      7
       2014-07-23      8

In [6]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',format='table')

In [7]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='date=20140722')
Out[7]: 
                   value
symbol date             
a      2014-07-22      1
b      2014-07-22      4
c      2014-07-22      7

In [12]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='symbol="a"')
Out[12]: 
                   value
symbol date             
a      2014-07-21      0
       2014-07-22      1
       2014-07-23      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeff has completely the right answer. I found a couple gotchas that I wanted to share and it won't fit in a comment - please consider this just a long form additional comment :)

(Pytables Versions)
If you get missing attribute or method errors when trying to write the hdf file you may want to try updating your PyTables version. Pandas (as of this writing) leverages Pytables and I found at least one pairing of versions that threw some odd errors until I updated Pytables and reloaded.

(Data types)
This may be fixed in Python 3 but in 2.7x the to_hdf has problems with unicode, with mixed data type columns, and with NaN values in floating point. Below is an example utility function to clean up a DataFrame in preparation for writing to_hdf that fixed all those problems for me. Note that this replaces NaN with zero, which was appropriate for my application but you may want to adjust that:

```html
def clean_cols_for_hdf(data):
    types = data.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))
    for col in types[types=='mixed'].index:
        data[col] = .data[col].astype(str)
    data[<your appropriate columns here>].fillna(0,inplace=True)
    return data
```

Some of this just extends one of Jeff's comments as well. Jeff is awesome, please excuse the added answer but I wanted to chip in some details that fixed things for me.

Comment: This will fill Na's but won't address the unicode issue

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck - Did you try and find that it didn't? Fixing unicode is what the .astype(str) in my code is for and it works on Python 2.7 at least when I try some simple examples right now. Do you have a specific case that doesn't handle?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work for me for some reason. I'm in Python 2.7. Not sure why. I ended up giving up.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck - Bummer. Hard to know what's going on without examples but I believe it - unicode is a mess and seems to get worse over time.