# Python/Pandas HDF5 - read condition with 'like'

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

Is there an equivalent of SQL 'like' that could be used when reading from a HDF5 store in Python/Pandas? I mean regex-ish expressions, to check if column values start / end with / contain certain strings. Something like:

```
df = pd.read_hdf(store, data, where= "column like '%blabla'")
```

(this doesn't work, obviously)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading in csv file as dataframe from hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642020/reading-in-csv-file-as-dataframe-from-hdfs)

Comment: Referenced material is a different question entirely...

Comment: Solved here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892904/python-pandas-store-a-data-frame-in-hdf5-with-a-multi-index

Comment: There's nothing there about 'like' operator, just regular wheres