# Pandas dataframe - what causes this error?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

My code:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(100)})
store = pd.HDFStore('mydata.h5')
store['obj1'] = frame
store['obj1_col'] = frame['a']
store.put('obj2',frame,foramt='table')
store.select('obj2',where=['index >= 10 and index <= 15'])
```

Gives this error message:

```
TypeError: cannot pass a where specification when reading from 
a Fixed format store. this store must be selected in its entirety
```

Why does this code give this error if every piece  of code is right? How do I avoid similar errors in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I wanted to comment, but I can't yet due to reputation...)

Hello, this is interesting -- for some reason it works on my machine. For the sake of completeness, I attach the code (with added imports).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(100)})
store = pd.HDFStore('mydata.h5')
store['obj1'] = frame
store['obj1_col'] = frame['a']
store.put('obj2',frame,format='table')
store.select('obj2',where=['index >= 10 and index <= 15'])
```

Returns

```
a
10  -0.049168
11  0.130048
12  -1.553641
13  -0.978392
14  0.723070
15  0.066814
```

Could you please mention the version of libraries you're using? I wonder if we might have different versions of libraries.
I have

```py
import tables
import sys
print(sys.version) # 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0]
print(pd.__version__) # 1.5.0
print(np.__version__) # 1.23.3
print(tables.__version__) # 3.8.0 ... (this one is dependency)
```

To clarify -- I have a suspicion that it might be connected to `pytables` version, [as referred in this, possibly related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28129429/13224210).

Could you try upgrading `pytables` (e.g. by `pip install --upgrade tables`) and run again?